# Animation module stops working properly if animation class is not unique on the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I've written a simple module to apply css classes from animate.css library.Classes are defined in html element data-attribute, but for some reason all animations work only if they are unique on the page, otherwise animation is implemented only to the last element with it's class.

Upd. Debugger in devtools shows that module iterates through each node, but still applies non-unique animations only to the last node.

Example:

```
<h2 id="1" class="module_animate-box" data-animate-trigger="scroll" data-animate-script='{"class":"zoomIn","position":"700"}'>Hello</h2>

<h2 id="2" class="module_animate-box" data-animate-trigger="scroll" data-animate-script='{"class":"zoomIn","position":"1000"}'>World</h2>
```

if you  use class "zoomIn" twice on the page, only id="2" will work.

```
import "./animate.css";

//check full list of availiable classes here: https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/README.md
export default class animationModule {
    constructor({
        selector
    }) {
        this.selector = selector;
        this.nodes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
        this.init();
    }

    getCoords(e) {//get coords of an element
        let coords = e.getBoundingClientRect();
        return coords;
    }

    getTriggerEvent(e){//get the appropriate  function by it's trigger type
        switch(e.dataset.animateTrigger){
            case "scroll":
                return this.onScroll
            break;
            case 'hover':
                return this.onHover
            break;
            case 'moved':
                return this.onMouseMove//sort of parallax
            default:
                return "loaded"
        }
    }

    onScroll(e,repeats,animationTriggerYOffset,isOutOfViewport,animationType){//if trigger === scroll
            e.style.animationIterationCount = repeats;//set iteration limits of animation
            window.onscroll= function(){         
               (window.pageYOffset >= animationTriggerYOffset && !(window.pageYOffset > isOutOfViewport.bottom)) ?//check if target el is in the trigger position and not out of the viewport
                     e.classList.add('animated', 'infinite', animationType.class) ://toggles on classes if everything is ok
                     e.classList.remove('animated', 'infinite', animationType.class)// toggles off classes if lower the defined trigger position or out of viewport
                     repeats = e.dataset.animateRepeat;//reset iteration for animation
                }        
    }

    onHover(e, repeats, animationTriggerYOffset, isOutOfViewport, animationType){//if trigger === hover

        e.style.animationIterationCount = repeats;//set iteration for animation
        e.addEventListener('mousemove', ()=> {
            e.classList.add('animated', 'infinite', animationType.class);
        })
        e.addEventListener('animationend', function () {//resets animation iteration
            e.classList.remove('animated', 'infinite', animationType.class)
        })

    }   

    onMouseMove(e, repeats, animationTriggerYOffset, isOutOfViewport, animationType){
        //in data-animate-script set values{"pageX":"#","pageY": "#"} the less the number the bigger the amplitude. negative numbers reverse the movement
        window.addEventListener('mousemove',(m) => {
            e.style.transform = `translate(${m.pageX * -1 / animationType.pageX}px, ${m.pageY * -1 / animationType.pageY}px)`
        })
    }

    init() {
        this.nodes.forEach(e => {

            console.log(e.dataset)
            let animationType = JSON.parse(e.dataset.animateScript);//define class name of animation needed to apply
            let repeats = e.dataset.animateRepeat || 'infinite';//define number of iterations for animation (INFINITE by default)
            let animationTriggerYOffset = animationType.position || 0;//defines YOffset to trigger animation(0 by default)
            let isOutOfViewport = this.getCoords(e);//sets coords of an element from getCoords function

            let action = this.getTriggerEvent(e);//get appropriate function depending on data-animate-trigger value

            action(e, repeats, animationTriggerYOffset, isOutOfViewport, animationType);//call appropriate function per each node
        })
}  
}
// Module data and attributes
// .module_animate-box - class that defines animation target
// data-animate-trigger - animation trigger(possible values: "scroll", "hover", "moved"(watches mouse movement))
// data-animate-repeat - number of repetitions (infinite by default)
// data-animate-script - JSON description of animation. example: '{"class":"wobble","position":"300"}' - will add class wobble when pageYoffset===300
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a little bit of trouble following, but I'd bet it's something object specific being written in window.onscroll

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, you were absolutely correct. My inattention srikes again.